# Multipe rewrite urls (domain.tld/blogs.php?user=username&post=postname TO username.domain.tld/posts/postname)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

How i can rewrite urls from this

*domain.tld/blogs.php?user=username&post=postname*

to this one:

*username.domain.tld/posts/postname*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure all of your links in your content look like this: `username.domain.tld/posts/postname`
2. Create a wildcard CNAME in DNS such that any subdomain get pointed to the server that hosts `domain.tld`, and they all share the same document root.
3. Add these rules to the htaccess file in the document root:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.) [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.tld$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]+)/?$ /blogs.php?username=%1&post=$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /blogs\.php\?user=([^&]+)&post=([^\ ]+))
   RewriteRule ^ http://%2.domain.tld/posts/%2 [L,R=301]
   ```